# Why is my map view callout translucent/transparent and how do I change it's color?

Tags: ios, ios7, mkmapview, mkannotationview

I'm on iOS 7 and I have the following problem. I can't find a clue after some research curiously...

I have a map view annotation with left and right accessories but transparent in the middle (default iOS 7 behavior I think).

How to change the default translucent/transparent background to any other color I want?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Is your `MKMapView` inside a `UITableViewCell`? I had a similar issue, where the `UITableViewCellSelectionStyle` of the cell caused this visual glitch.

Setting it to `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone` fixed it for me.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly my case. thank you for your help. For the moment I have just put my Map out of the table. Thanks again.

Comment: I just spent hours trying to figure this out. Thank you very much. This issue also happens for me in iOS 8

Comment: Thanks, you have saved me from a lot of wasted time!

Comment: Still an issue on iOS10.3. Thanks for the saved time.