# iOS Background MKPointAnnotation

Tags: ios, dictionary, annotations

I've map view in which I've few MKPointAnnotation.

All it's working, BUT, the "background" of the view's MKPoiintAnnotation are "invisible", and so it's not very "visible".

I wanted to change te background to white, I tried to use :

- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id )annotation

But I didn't succeed to change the background with this method. What I need to use ? Thx,

EDIT : By "background", I want to mean, the background under the text "Current Location" (for this example) :

[image]

EDIT 2 :

I'm using this code to add annotation :

```
                annotationPoint = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
            annotationCoord.latitude = [[item getPlace] getLatitude];
            annotationCoord.longitude = [[item getPlace] getLongitude];
            annotationPoint.coordinate = annotationCoord;
            annotationPoint.title = item.getNom;
            annotationPoint.subtitle = [Utils getDateString :item.getDeadline :@"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"];
            [_mapView addAnnotation:annotationPoint];
```

Comment: What do you mean by "background"?

Comment: Wait, I take a screen :)

Comment: can you post the whole code?

Comment: but I don't think it's bug from my code, because the "current location" is not created by me. There should be an option to change this...

Comment: you can set GPS coordinates under iOS Simulator>Debug>Location. Did u know this? Your code seems fine, it should work properly

Comment: Did you declare your mapView's property as strong, nonatomic?

Comment: mhhh, I think you didn't understand my problem ^^ I juste want to have a background color under the text "Current Location", because currently, it's not very visible...

Comment: Is your MKMapView inside a `UITableViewCell`?  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20011902/why-is-my-map-view-callout-translucent-transparent-and-how-do-i-change-its-colo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build a custom annotation, you might want to follow this tutorial:

http://blog.asynchrony.com/2010/09/building-custom-map-annotation-callouts-part-2/

Comment: Do you have the same problem with your other annotations?

Comment: Hum, it's not my problem :/

Answer (score 0):

If your MapView is within a UITableView then you need to set the selectionStyle to UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None.

For example in Swift, I added the following to the awakeFromNib function of the custom table cell class:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    // Selection style for the cell
    self.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
}
```