# MKMapView showing clear annotations

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview

I have a `MKMapView` inside a static cell of a child `UITableViewController` of a `UIViewController`. As highlighted in the image below, the annotation does not have a white background and the unselected pins have a darker tint to them. Is this just an apple bug, or is there a way to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20011902/why-is-my-map-view-callout-translucent-transparent-and-how-do-i-change-its-colo.  By the way, it's not the "annotation" that's showing as clear but the annotation's _callout_.

Comment: Why did like 1000 google searches not bring this answer up haha but thanks so much @Anna

Answer (score -2):

storyboard cell -> selecition->none